# Jquery/JS that "appendsTO" makes inside function not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, date

Basically each time I click on the `.addScnt` `button` it adds a `form` to the page at the `.p_scents` `div`, but the `date picker range` `input` fails to work if the `form` is added through the button.
If I put him in the page by copy pasting the code in the html file it works just fine.

This being my function:

```
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('.p_scents');
    $('.addScnt').on('click', function() {
    $('/* removed long strip of code for easier reading */').appendTo(scntDiv); 
        return false;
    });
});
```

From reading on the interwebs I found something about "Direct and delegated events" but I'm still not able to figure out what i'm doing wrong.

**EDIT to try to clarify:**

This works.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-3 no-padding-right" for="date-range-picker">Start/End Date:</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                      <div class="clearfix">
                        <input class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 date-range-picker" type="text" name="date-range-picker" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
  </div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('.date-range-picker').daterangepicker().prev().on(ace.click_event, function(){
          $(this).next().focus();
        });
```

And this doesn't.

**Jquery+HTML:**

```
$(function() {
          var scntDiv = $('.p_scents');
          var i = $('.p_scents').size();
          $('.addScnt').on('click', function() {
            $(' <div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-3 no-padding-right" for="date-range-picker">Start/End Date:</label> <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9"> <div class="clearfix"> <input class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 date-range-picker" type="text" name="date-range-picker" /> </div> </div> </div>').appendTo(scntDiv); i++;
            return false;
          });
        });
```

Comment: because you need to initialize those widgets...They are not magically wired up.

Comment: Is there any chance you could link me to an example so I get a better idea of the issue?

Comment: You need to call `$( ".YourElem" ).datepicker();` after adding the new html to the page!

Answer (score 1):

Each time you add to the DOM new event handlers need to be set up for those particular nodes.. So after appending, attach a listener for that datepicker. Even better; set up an event handler for all datepickers in advance by using something like `$('.allMyFormsDiv').find('.datePicker').on('focus', openDatePicker)`

If that does not answer your question, please post a fiddle(/whatever) link if that not shows off what goes wrong, it's a bit hard to understand without.

Comment: I tried to implement your way but to no success. So I updated my original question with an edit of the code snippets to help clarify the situation, it contains most of the important code. Sadly that's all I'm able to post so I hope it's enough.